# How do I know what a particular driver is used for?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, reboot, dump

Every few days my Asus X556UJ computer (Win 10 64-bit) restarts, sometimes with a blue screen of death (DPC Wachdog Violation). The dump files suggest that the issue is cased by the driver "wdiwifi.sys":

> Probably caused by : wdiwifi.sys ( wdiwifi!CNdisSpinLockContext::EnterCriticalSection+13 )

How do I find out which device uses this driver?

Comment: your wifi device.  Wireless network adapter.

Comment: As @Adrien stated it is your wifi driver.  What is the specific error message that you get on the BSOD?  On an ASUS I had a few years back I would get the "Driver IRQL Not Less Or Equal" due to wdiwifi.sys, and updating the driver for my wireless card remedied this issue.

Comment: The BSOD message is "DPC Watchdog Violation". I am not sure which particular device this relates to though: I have "Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC" and "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller", but the drivers listed for them do not include wdiwifi.sys

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn897672(v=vs.85).aspx Like others said though: The filename is a dead giveaway. It’s about WiFi (aka WLAN, Wireless LAN).

Comment: update all network card drivers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, like in your case, the filename of the driver may give away what device the driver is for.

Without using any third party tools, the next step would be to look in the registry, all drivers are listed there. You can use `regedit.exe` or PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\system\currentcontrolset\services  | ForEach-Object {if ($_.GetValue("ImagePath") -like "*wdiwifi.sys"){$_.GetValue("DisplayName"), $_.Name,$_.GetValue("ImagePath")}}
```

Just replace the filename with whatever you are looking for, in your case we get:

```
WDI Driver Framework
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\services\wdiwifi
system32\DRIVERS\wdiwifi.sys
```

which shows us the Display name of the driver, the registry location as well as the file location. You may want to search online to find more information about that driver.

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid this does not answer the question however. I do not seem to have any device called wdiwifi in my laptop.